# Django error - __str__ returned non-string (type User)

Tags: django, django-models

I have the below 2 models - User and PhoneProfile.

I can successfully create records for User. When i browse to PhoneProfile using admin console, i can see the foreign key present. On selection of an entry and completion of the rest of the fields, i get the error below.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    phone_regex     = RegexValidator(regex = r'^\+?1?\d{2,14}$', message = "Phone number must be in the format: '+xxxxxxxxxx'.")
    phone           = models.CharField(validators = [phone_regex], max_length = 15, unique = True)
    first_name      = models.CharField(max_length = 50, blank = False, null = False)
    last_name       = models.CharField(max_length = 50, blank = False, null = False)
    email           = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank = True, null = True)
    first_login     = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    active          = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    staff           = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    admin           = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    timestamp       = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD  = 'phone'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects         = UserManager()
```

```
class PhoneProfile(models.Model):
    registered_phone =  models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='registered_phone')
    notify_enable_low_bal = models.BooleanField()
    notify_amount_low_bal = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10000, default='50', null=True)
```

Error message when i attempt to create an entry in PhoneProfile model

```
__str__ returned non-string (type User)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/smartrecharge/phoneprofile/add/
Django Version: 3.0.7
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
__str__ returned non-string (type User)
Exception Location: /Users/django-backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py in log_addition, line 807
Python Executable:  /Users/django-backend/venv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.7.7
Python Path:
```

Any guide will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the value you are getting in the class string representation is non string so you have to change the def **str**(self) method and convert returning data into string and if there is no data than make one like given below

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    phone_regex     = RegexValidator(regex = r'^\+?1?\d{2,14}$', message = "Phone number must be in the format: '+xxxxxxxxxx'.")
    phone           = models.CharField(validators = [phone_regex], max_length = 15, unique = True)
    first_name      = models.CharField(max_length = 50, blank = False, null = False)
    last_name       = models.CharField(max_length = 50, blank = False, null = False)
    email           = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank = True, null = True)
    first_login     = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    active          = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    staff           = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    admin           = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    timestamp       = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD  = 'phone'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects         = UserManager()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.phone_regex)
```

do the same changes in the other class you specify in the question